# Image object from BLOB?

Tags: java, mysql, blob, inputstream, javax.imageio

I'm having trouble getting an image object from a BLOB stored in a mySQL table.

Table "images" has values: "idImage" (int), "idArticle" (int), "image" (BLOB).

This is a method from the database access object:

```
public MyImage findImageById(int idImage) {
    executor = new DbOperationExecutor();
    sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE idImage = '" + idImage + "';";
    dbOperation = new ReadOperation(sql);
    ResultSet rs = executor.executeOperation(dbOperation).getResultSet();
    MyImage i = new MyImage();
    try {
        rs.next();
        if (rs.getRow() == 1) {
            i.setIdImage(rs.getInt("idImage"));
            i.setIdArticle(rs.getInt("idArticle"));
            i.setImage(ImageBusiness.getInstance().getImageByBlob(rs.getBlob("image")));
        }
        return immagine;
    } catch (SQLException e) {...} catch (NullPointerException e) {...}
    finally {
        executor.close(dbOperation);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Method "getImageByBlob" in ImageBusiness class is:

```
public Image getImageByBlob(Blob blob){
    try {
        InputStream stream = blob.getBinaryStream();
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream);
        return image;
    } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Blob-Image conversion Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I debug this code I notice that Image.read(stream) return null, why?? Help me please.

Comment: Use **placeholder values** in your SQL queries or you end up with awful [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com). That in this particular case it's an `int` is irrelevant. You're using a dangerous pattern here.

Comment: First step: Are you getting the right image data? Look at the first few bytes. A PNG, for example, has a [very specific start sequence](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html).

Comment: Try getting the image directly out of the `ResultSet` without going via a `Blob`

Comment: `ImageIO.read(stream)` returns `null` for file formats it does not support. What file format is your blob? The easiest way to find out is to inspect the blob directly in a database tool, or dump the blob to disk and use a tool like `file` or a hex viewer to inspect the file header. Of course, if you also have access to the code that wrote the blob, that is good place to look... 

Answer (score -1):

Only one "return" statement ever allowed in a method!.

```
public Image getImageByBlob(Blob blob)throws IOException,SQLException {
        InputStream stream = blob.getBinaryStream();
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream);
return image;
}
```